# Using BroadcastReceiver to launch SyncAdapter

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to use a BroadcastReceiver to trigger the SyncAdapter when there are changes in the database server (using GCM).

When the receiver is told to start the sync process, I get the following error

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(accounts[0], AUTHORITY, null);
```

This is what my BroadcastReceiver looks like

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "GcmBroadcastReceiver";

    public static final String AUTHORITY = TournamentContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;
    public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = TournamentContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;
    public static final String ACCOUNT = "default_account";

    // Incoming Intent key for extended data
    public static final String KEY_SYNC_REQUEST = "com.example.android.datasync.KEY_SYNC_REQUEST";
    public static final String MESSAGE_TYPE = "gcm";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: here");
        // Get a GCM object instance
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm =
                GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);

        // Get the type of GCM message
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        /*
         * Test the message type and examine the message contents.
         * Since GCM is a general-purpose messaging system, you
         * may receive normal messages that don't require a sync
         * adapter run.
         * The following code tests for a a boolean flag indicating
         * that the message is requesting a transfer from the device.
         */
        if (MESSAGE_TYPE.equals(messageType) && intent.getBooleanExtra(KEY_SYNC_REQUEST, true)) {
            AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
            Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType(ACCOUNT_TYPE);

            if (accounts.length == 0) {
                // todo create account if not already there
            }

            /*
             * Signal the framework to run your sync adapter. Assume that
             * app initialization has already created the account.
             */
            ContentResolver.requestSync(accounts[0], AUTHORITY, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I am confident my SyncAdapter is working fine because I have not noticed any problems in the periodic sync.

How do you think I can resolve this?

Thank you in advance! :D

Comment: Please actually include the error

Comment: Sorry about that. Will do it for the next question. The answer that I have accepted helped me through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't post the actual error, so it's hard to say what else might be wrong, but there is definitely one thing that is wrong:

The `extras` parameter of [`requestSync(Account, String, Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#requestSync%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) must not be `null`.

If you look into the sources you'll the that the `extras` value is explicitly checked for `null`.

Here is the relevant code snipped of [ContentResolver.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/ContentResolver.java#1765)

```
public static void requestSync(Account account, String authority, Bundle extras) {
    requestSyncAsUser(account, authority, UserHandle.myUserId(), extras);
}

public static void requestSyncAsUser(Account account, String authority, int userId,
        Bundle extras) {
    if (extras == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must specify extras.");
    }
```

So you can see that `requestSync` calls `requestSyncAsUser` which throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if the `extras` `Bundle` is `null`.

If you don't have any extras to pass you should pass [`Bundle.EMPTY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#EMPTY) like so:

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(accounts[0], AUTHORITY, Bundle.EMPTY);
```

Comment: Sorry about not posting the entire error. What you suggested worked. Thank you!